# ORA-04091: table xyz.xyz is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, ora-04091

So, I have create the trigger which will update the data in table if it's null.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "XDA.GUID"
AFTER INSERT ON "TEST_GUID" 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.GUID IS NULL THEN
        UPDATE "TEST_GUID"
        SET GUID = SYS_GUID()
        WHERE ID = :NEW.ID;
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
END;
```

I need to update the same table after insertion perform on that table.

Now i'm trying to perform

```
INSERT INTO TEST_GUID (ID, GUID)
VALUES (2, '');
```

then i'm getting below error.

```
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
INSERT INTO TEST_GUID (ID, GUID)
VALUES (2, '')
Error report -
ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.TEST_GUID is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.XDA.GUID", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.XDA.GUID'
```

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's just

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "XDA.GUID"
BEFORE INSERT ON "TEST_GUID" 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.guid := nvl(:new.guid, sys_guid());
END;
```

BTW, why are you rolling it back? Then there's no use in that trigger at all.

Comment: try your suggestion but its not working showing error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "XDA.GUID"
AFTER INSERT ON "TEST_GUID" 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.GUID := NVL(:NEW.GUID, SYS_GUID());
END;
Error report -
ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type
04084. 00000 -  "cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"
*Cause:    New trigger variables can only be changed in before row
           insert or update triggers.
*Action:   Change the trigger type or remove the variable reference.
```

Comment: Certainly; should've been BEFORE INSERT. I apologize.

Comment: Why need to do Before Insert?
is there any reason?

Comment: Because - as error told you - you can't do it in AFTER trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "XDA.GUID"
  BEFORE INSERT ON TEST_GUID
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.guid IS NULL)
BEGIN
  :NEW.guid := sys_guid();
END;
/
```

To only run the trigger on `NULL` values. (*Note: In Oracle, `''` and `NULL` are identical.*)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oiY0O66E)